# Kernel dead after running tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, conda

When i try to run this code :

```
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = np.array(Image.open(image_path))
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(model, image_np)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks_reframed', None),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)

  display(Image.fromarray(image_np))
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  show_inference(detection_model, image_path)
```

for some reasons it keep showing "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

Previously i was able to run this code.. but now it keep showing the kernel died

i've try to update the environment using conda update mkl

TensorFlow installed from (source or binary):
installed using pip(pip install tensorflow-gpu)
TF Version: 2.0
How to reproduce:
run the object_detection_tutorial.ipynb file

Comment: previously with earlier tf? P/S/I am not able to run tf on my mac pro 2009 because of the unsupported cpu instructions, tf not builded to run on. maybe it's your case too.

Comment: tf version 1.15 able to run

Comment: I assume tf 2.0 compiled with a different set of CPU instructions than tf 1.5, and your computer doesn't support new ones.